# how do python handle asynchronous task

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, django

I've strong background in a JS frameworks. Javascript is single threaded language and during the execution of code when it encounters any async task, the event loop plays the important role there.

Now I've been into Python/Django and things are going good but I'm very curious about how python handle any asynchronous tasks whenever I need to make a database query in django, I simple use the queryset method like

```py
def func(id):
    do_somthing()
    user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    do_somthing_with_user()


func()
another_func()
```

I've used the queryset method that fetch something from database and is a asynchronous function without await keyword. what will be the behaviour of python there, is it like block the execution below until the queryset response, is it continue the execution for the rest of code on another thread.

Also whenever we need to make an external request from python, we uses requests library method without await keyword,

```py
r = request.get("https://api.jsonplaceholder.com/users")
# will the below code executes when the response of the request arrive?
do_somthing()
.
.
.
do_another_thing()
```

does python block the execution of code until the response arrives?

In JS the async task is handled by event loop while the rest of  the code executes normally

```js
console.log("first")

fetch("https://api.jsonplaceholder.com/users").then(() => console.log("third"))

console.log("second")
```

the logs in console will be

first
second
third

**How Python Handles these type things under the hood?**

Answer (score 0):

The `await` command needs to be used specifically when you are running an asynchronous function that calls synchronous functions. This synchronous function is ran as a coroutine and has an object name `coroutine` when debugging. To run a coroutine, it must be scheduled on the event loop. Using the
`await` keyword releases control back to the event loop. Instead of awaiting a coroutine, you can also setup a task to schedule a coroutine to run at a certain time using the `asyncio` package. See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks)

```
asyncio.create_task(coro, *, name=None, context=None)
```

Python does not block execution but rather ensures that it happens at the correct time using CPU parallelism. Using a method like `request.get()` should not create any forthcoming errors because you are accessing values over the internet and not locally. Network requests move, essentially at the speed of light, where as database requests on the server are limited by the speed of the SSD or HDD. This was more of an issue on old drives where you are literally waiting for a disk to spin, but the idea of properly managing these local resources is still a issue that has to be solved in order for the asynchronous application to work. When making calls to the sql database, make sure to use the decorator `@database_sync_to_async` above the regular 'synchronous' functions that your asynchronous function calls.

```
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
```

For more information check out the django documentation on [asynchronous support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/async/).

Answer (score -1):

In Django, when performing database queries using its ORM (Object-Relational Mapping), such as `User.objects.get(id=id)`, the operation is synchronous by default. This means that the code execution will pause until the query completes and the result is returned, similar to synchronous operations in JavaScript.

For example:

```py
def func(id):
    do_something()
    user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    do_something_with_user()

func()
another_func()
```

In this code snippet, the execution of `func()` will halt at the database query line until the query finishes. Once the user object is retrieved, `do_something_with_user()` will execute, followed by `another_func()`.

Similarly, when making external requests using the `requests` library, the operation is synchronous. The code execution will block until the response is received.

For instance:

```py
import requests

r = requests.get("https://api.jsonplaceholder.com/users")
# Code execution will pause here until the response is received
do_something()
# Execution continues after the response arrives
do_another_thing()
```

In this scenario, `do_something()` will not execute until the response is received because the code is blocked until `requests.get()` completes its operation.

To handle asynchronous tasks in Python, consider using the `asyncio` library. Here's an example of how you can use `asyncio` to perform asynchronous tasks:

```py
import asyncio

async def fetch_user(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.json()

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        user = await fetch_user(session, "https://api.jsonplaceholder.com/users")
        print(user)

asyncio.run(main())
```

In this example, `asyncio` is used to asynchronously fetch a user from an external API. The `fetch_user` function performs an asynchronous HTTP request using `aiohttp`. The `main` function is defined as `async`, and it orchestrates the asynchronous tasks using `asyncio.run()`. When executed, this code will asynchronously fetch a user from the API and print the user data.